# why this code call general template function in GCC?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

// define the general compare template
 template <class T>
 int compare(const T& t1, const T& t2) {
   cout<< "Common_T"<<endl;
   return 0;

 }
 template<>
 int compare<const char*>( const char * const& s1,
                          const char * const& s2)
 {
    cout<< "Special_T"<<endl;
    return 0;
 }
typedef const char  char6[6];
     template<>
             int compare<char6>(const char6& s1,const char6& s2)
    {
            cout << "Special_Char6_T" << endl;
             return 0;
    }

 int main() {
     int i = compare("hello" , "world");
 }
```

the result is:

```
Common_T
```

My question is: why don't output "Special_Char6_T"???

Comment: What do you get when you change your code to `int i = compare("hello" , 5);`? A compilation error for sure. But I think the parameter types will be included in the diagnostic message, so this probably will answer your question.

Comment: VC2010 outputs Special_Char6_T

Comment: but why VC2010 outputs Special_Char6_T ?

Comment: @hu wang: Or why gcc doesn't? I don't know yet. interesting, if _const_ is removed from typedef (typedef char6[6];) then GCC outputs Special_Char6_T too. Seems it is some subtle thing related to (possible) "double const" collapsing with typedef

Comment: With C++2011, it is a good use case for `typedef std::array<char,6> char6`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct template specialization that matches your c strings.

```
typedef char char6[6];
template<> int compare<char6>(char6 const &s1,char6 const &s2)
{
    cout << "Special_Char6_T" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Mehrdad read from right to left "s1 is a reference to const "char6 type" "
Which expands to "s1 is a reference to const char array of size six"

Comment: Oooh... I thought it was a variable declaration; I didn't see the `typedef`!! Very sorry about that.

Comment: @huwang cannot convert ‘const char [6]’ to ‘main()::wtf’ in assignment
is what I get when I do enum wtf{}; wtf lol; lol= "hello"; so yes, according to gcc it is an array of const char, which is standards compliant.

Answer (score -1):

Intuitively, because the dimension of arrays is not part of their type. That dimension matters only for variables and fields. So both

```
  char hello[6]="hello";
```

and

```
  char longstring[] = "a very very long string should be here";
```

have both the same type `char[]`

and

```
 typedef char t1[6];
```

and

```
 typedef char t2[];
```

are aliases for the "same" type.

(You could look at the [mangled function names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) to have a clue)

Comment: Your intuition is wrong. The array bound is definitely part of its type. That's why `sizeof(t1)` is 6. If the array bound wasn't part of the type, `sizeof` couldn't deduce that.

Comment: @MSalters: I agree to your opinion

Comment: The `sizeof` is not really part of the type; otherwise a `char*` argument and a `char[]` formal won't fit. They definitely have different `sizeof`.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: What do you mean, "won't fit"? Also, do note that the type of `longstring` in your example is NOT `char[]`. That's just a shorthand declaration. The compiler will deduce the type to `char[39]` from the length of its initial value.

Comment: Take `puts` as an example: you can call it with argument `const char hello[]="hello";` whose `sizeof` is 6 or with `const char*p = strdup("foobarbarbar");` whose `sizeof` is `sizeof(void*)` ie 8 on 64 bits machine. So the `sizeof` is not part of the argument's type.